# Is it possible to build App Clip without having a full app?

Tags: ios14, apple-appclips

Is it possible to register only AppClip in app connect instead of full app?
Is there a way by which we can hide bottom app banner from App Clip and just use clips?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No - the app clip must be accompanied by your full app. When you create an app clip target in Xcode, it must include a parent application identifier in its entitlements file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.developer.associated-domains</key>
    <array>
        <string>appclips:example.com</string>
    </array>
    <key>com.apple.developer.parent-application-identifiers</key>
    <array>
        <string>$(AppIdentifierPrefix)com.myparent.app</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

The image you have posted is of a layout that is used for all app clips, where you supply the image, subtitle, and text for the call to action button. The presentation of the card is handled by the system and cannot be modified to hide any elements.